# Only submit form when there are no validation errors

Tags: jquery, validation

Im currently running validation on an input field containing email.
When clicking submit and if the email field doesnt validate, then I show an error overlay.

My problem right now is, that the form submit regardsless of validating or not.
How do I make it submit ONLY when everything validates (in my example the email field)

```
var clicked = $("button");

clicked.click(function() {
    var email = $("input[type='email']").val();
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        //Show validation error
    } else {
        //Dont show validation error
    }
});
```

[Fiddle of my setup here](http://jsfiddle.net/2FfQw/)

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless you are using the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the event into the click function, then call `preventDefault` on the event if validation fails.  [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)  will prevent the default action of an event from occuring.

```
var clicked = $("button");

clicked.click(function(e) {
    var email = $("input[type='email']").val();
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        //Dont show validation error
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2FfQw/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. My favourite is hooking to the form submit event, and return false if validation failed:

```
$('#form-id').submit(function() {
  // do validation

  if (!valid)
    return false;

  // if it's valid it will submit, no need to return true
}
```

It's also a good hook to use if you want to use ajax for submit.